# How do I document my code to understand how it flows (works)?

Tags: language-agnostic

I am writing a small game,and I now have 9 C# scripts that make it work. I have lost track of what exactly is happening and how. I want to know how things work from the moment the game starts. Whats happening and how, etc.

I am a beginner, and I have heard that writing down your program flow is called documenting it. How can I document? Do I have to write comments everywhere in my code to explain the flow of the program?

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. Documenting software is a topic that people could write (and have written) books and university courses about.

Comment: Ok but give me somewhere to start man. I'm clueless, really.

Comment: Put a comment block at the start of each script.  List what other scripts call this script, and what other scripts this script calls.  Add in a little narrative to describe what the script does.  Also draw up an overall flowchart with all the scripts on it and how/why/when control passes from one to another.  Doing that will help you see the overall shape of the thing.  Next time start with the top level design and add more detail to the documentation as you develop lower and lower detail.

Comment: Thank you for your help, dude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting extensive comments into your code is not a good approach. Basically you should try to make your code as self-explanatory as possible. You do this by carefully planning what belongs into a class or function and by using meaningful names for your classes, functions and variables. Comments are nothing but a last resort if additional explanation is really required.

In most cases you should also also have some documents in addition to the code that explain certain aspects of your software:

- Requirements document - what is the purpose of the software, how is it used
- Architecture and design specification - what are the modules and classes of the software and how do they interact. Often this document mainly consists of one or more diagrams (UML or something else).
- Build manual - how to compile and link the software
- Installation instructions
- User manual

This list is neither complete nor is it mandatory. If, for example, the user interface of your software is simple and self-explaining, you probably won't need a user manual.

Comment: Thank you, I'll do that.

Comment: @downvoter: please explain and help me improve my answer

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes diagrams make better documentation than text.  There is a standard way of diagramming a control flow (whether it's of a program or a business process).  They're called ... wait for it ... [control-flow diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow_diagram).  But I don't think that's exactly what you're after.

There are also [flow charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart) (often spelled as one word), which may be more suited to software than general control-flow diagrams.  Flow charts can be useful for understanding an algorithm, but they generally don't give a good big-picture view.

With a complicated program, what might be more important to keep in mind is the *data* flow.  For those we have ... can you guess? ... [data-flow diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_flow_diagram) (DFDs).

DFDs can be drawn at varying levels of detail.  You can have a high-level one that shows the major components of the system and how they fit together and low-level ones that show the nitty-gritty details for the portions of the system that require more detail.

DFDs can be used for a variety of analyses, including things like threat modeling.  But I find them great for getting an overview of what's-what when I'm looking at a new project (or one I've forgotten about).  You should be able to find some tutorials about DFDs online, and I think some drawing software (like Visio) have templates specifically for DFDs (and probably the other types of diagrams I've mentioned).

Some might consider DFDs a bit old-school and prefer more rigorous systems like UML ([Unified Modeling Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language)), which is capable of expressing many more concepts and of having a very direct mapping between your "model" and your code.  I've never learned enough UML to get much use out of it.  The diagrams in many books on software patterns are expressed in UML.